# Javascript google maps api addDomListener changes context of this

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am doing some work with the GoogleMaps API and have created a module to hold some custom functions:

```
myFuncs = {
  doStuff: function() {
     console.log('I am doing stuff');
  },
  callStuff: function() {
     console.log('I am calling doStuff');
     this.doStuff();
  }
}
```

This seems about right for what I need. But when I do this:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('myButton'), 'click', myFuncs.callStuff);
```

When the button is clicked I get  the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLButtonElement> has no method 'doStuff'
```

I understand here that the context of `this` has changed due to binding to the Dom object but I do not fully understand what is happening or how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the function call in an anonymous function.  For example:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('scrollToForm'), 'click', function(){myFuncs.callStuff()});
```

I just ran this and it seems to be working.

---

EDIT

echoing `this` when you don't use the anonymous function shows that you are in the context opf whatever object you have bound to.  Firing it from within the anonymous functions sets your context to the object you are calling.  Not sure if it is the best way, but it does work.  Instead of using `this` you could explicitly call out the object.  IE

```
myFuncs = {
  doStuff: function() {
     console.log('I am doing stuff');
  },
  callStuff: function() {
     console.log('I am calling stuff');
     myFuncs.doStuff();
  }
}
```

This takes out any way confusion in context.

Comment: Right. This does in fact work! I wondering if this is the best option given how I set things up?

Comment: I added an edit with another way to do it.  Without knowing why you are setting up your functions like this I don't know if I can get more specific.  You could always send the callback function as an argument.  I have found that particular method helpful on occassion

Comment: Yeah, I'm finding that being explicit is probably better here. But you did answer my original question - much appreciated!